# How to convert Pennylane decompose_hamiltonian to Cirq PauliString?

Tags: programming, hamiltonian-simulation, cirq, pennylane

I have a matrix that I would like to decompose into a Pauli String. Pennylane's
qml.utils.decompose_hamiltonian does this and returns a list of coefficients and a list of operations representing the decomposition.

Is there any simple way to convert the format of the returned operations, i.e.
from `Identity(wires=[0]) @ PauliZ(wires=[1])` (Pennylane syntax) to
`cirq.PauliString(cirq.I(qubits[0]), cirq.Z(qubits[1]))`?

Answer (score 1):

Use Pennylane's `pauli_word_to_string` function to convert `Identity(wires=[0]) @ PauliZ(wires=[1])` to string. Then use `cirq.DensePauliString(str).sparse()` to convert this string to `PauliString`:

```
coeffs, obs_list = decompose_hamiltonian(A)

# Get PauliStrings:
for op in obs_list:
    print(cirq.DensePauliString(pauli_word_to_string(op)).sparse())

# Get PauliSum:
pauli_sum = cirq.PauliSum.from_pauli_strings([
    cirq.DensePauliString(pauli_word_to_string(op), coefficient = coeffs[index]).sparse()
        for index, op in enumerate(obs_list)
])
```